# How to make this regex negation

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I have the following code:

```
$content = eregi_replace('!([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', '<a href="http://www.example.com/link/\\1">\\1</a>', $content);
```

that works perfectly, but I wish it ignores repeated words.

e.g.:

> !stack!
>   stack! !overflow! !overflow

he should get only the first and ignore repeated, thus not making the link.

Comment: repetitions must be deleted?

Comment: Please explain more detailed what you want to get.

Comment: You should be using [`preg_replace()`](http://uk3.php.net/preg_replace) not [`eregi_replace()`](http://uk3.php.net/eregi_replace) as it has been [deprecated](http://uk3.php.net/eregi_replace) (though that's not the reason for this not doing what you want of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) and it's `limit` parameter

```
$content = '!stack! stack! !overflow! !overflow';
$newcontent = preg_replace('#!([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#','<a href="http://www.example.com/link/\\1">\\1</a>',$content,1);
```

Comment: That would only replace once. I think that OP wants to replace each different word once. Not just one word.